# Using Table Based Layouts for Browsers IE 7 in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I have this code,

```
#if ($browserSniffer.isIe($request) && $browserSniffer.getMajorVersion($request) < 8)
```

in my page layouts in Liferay to tell them to use table based Layouts for browser IE 7, but I get the following warning:

```
Invalid character used in text string ( #if($browserSniffer.isIe($request) && $browserSniffer.getMajorVersion($request) < 8) ).
```

The problem seems to be the AND (&&) parameter, but I don't see any problem in that. So, I would be grateful if someone could tell me what the problem is.

Thanks in advance, Adia.

---

### UPDATE: The layout file

```
<div class="default-page-template" id="main-content" role="main">
   #if ($browserSniffer.isIe($request) && $browserSniffer.getMajorVersion($request) < 8)
    <table class="portlet-layout">
            <tr>
                <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-1">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
                </td>
                <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-2">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-3">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="portlet-layout">
            <tr>
                <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-4">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
                </td>
                <td class="portlet-column" id="column-5">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-5", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
                </td>
                <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-6">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-6", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="portlet-layout">
            <tr>
                <td class="portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-7">
                    $processor.processColumn("column-7", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    #else
        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-1">
                $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
            </div>

            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-2">
                $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-3">  
                $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-4">
               $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
            </div>

            <div class="portlet-column" id="column-5">
                $processor.processColumn("column-5", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
            </div>

            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-6">
            $processor.processColumn("column-6", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
            </div>          
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-7">
                $processor.processColumn("column-7", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
            </div>
        </div>

    #end
</div>
```

Comment: Which Liferay version do you use? Can you post the full layout-template?

Comment: I am using Liferay 6.0.6. The whole layout looks messy in IE 7 due that warning. In other browsers, it works nicely. I just added the whole layout to the first post.

Comment: looks good - just like any other layout-template in Liferay. Is there anything with more detail than the message stated in the logs?

Comment: Actually nothing. It's just the above log plus this other warning that says: Undefined attribute name (role), basically complaining about the role 'main' which should be also fine.

Comment: An the problem type is marked as 'HTML problem' in the Eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily determine and workaround the && problem, if that's indeed the problem - though it'd be the way that velocity handles logical operators:

```
#if ($browserSniffer.isIe($request))
  #if($browserSniffer.getMajorVersion($request) < 8)
     ... (your stuff here)
  #end
#end
```

If it isn't at least you get the new error message in only half the statement and can continue debugging from there.

In what kind of file do you have this? Layout-Template? Theme?

Comment: I have this in the layout files. After trying your way, it started complaining about the "less than" sign "<"; So the problem seems to be something else.